# Writing to terminals of other users

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

I know that you can use `write` or `wall` to write to users but you can't use these to send `sl`. I tried sending it through `/dev/pts/*` but that is strictly controlled, so that only the owner and tty are allowed to interact with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I freaking did it:

Add the user(eg: nick) that will run sl to the sudoers file

```
[nick@houston ~]$ sudo grep nick /etc/sudoers
nick  ALL=(ALL)         NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Open 2 putty session say `/dev/pts/0` and `/dev/pts/1`

Login to `/dev/pts/1` with any user

Login to `/dev/pts/0` with user `nick` and run the following command:

```
sl | sudo tee /dev/pts/1
```

Comment: you realize root can always write to anything, yeah? doing `sudo` here kind of defeats the purpose of answering a question about  bypassing file permissions.

Comment: Also, if you are going to suggest using sudo, could you please use a more restricted config for demo as many copy/paste?